# Android: Replace overflow menu with normal button

Tags: android, button, menu

I'm trying to replace the overflow menu with a normal Imagebutton, i do not want drop down menu. the same as DisplayHome button is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add the attribute: `android:showAsAction="always"`** to your menu item to keep it out of the overflow menu.

Something like this probably:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/myMenuItem"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/myTitle"/>

</menu>
```

---

Additionally, if you want to only show the menu button if there is room and otherwise store it in the overflow menu, use: `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`.